# UID of Type V tag seems to be "backwards"

Tags: android, nfc, iso-15693

I am building an app that uses RFID tags to identify users, using NFC. I can correctly read the tags, there is no problem. However, when I use the "NFC TagInfo" app, I received this ID from a Type V tag:

```
e00401007539c2d3
```

when I read the tag myself, the UID is completely backwards:

```
d3c23975000104e0
```

The RF technology for the Type V tag is *Type V (ISO/IEC 15693 / Vicinity)*. There seems to be nothing wrong with my code, as other tags (*Type A (ISO/IEC 14443 Type A*) work fine. This is how I convert the `byte[]` to `String`:

```
public static String tagFromByte(byte[] __tagId) {
    String tagId = "";

    for (byte b: __tagId) {
        tagId += String.format("%02x", b);
    }

    return tagId;
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getId%28%29):

> The size and format of an ID is specific to the RF technology used by the tag.

I tried to search for more info on how to read the UID for a specific technology, but couldn't find any.

**Update** [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1Qqs-Q0aCI4) I found, it is according to documentation. But, that leads to the question, how to get the tag's RF technology used to trigger the right UID `byte[]-to-string` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You are logging you tag from 0 to 7, while it should be the other way around.

The `tagId[0]` byte is the least significant byte, and therefore goes at the end.

Log it like so:

```
for (int i = _tagId.length(); i > 0; --i) {
    tagId += String.format("%02x", _tagId[i]);
}
```

Comment: I understand, but this breaks TypeA tags (they will be backwards). I seem to have found the answer though. `getTechList` gives me the used RF tech type, which I can use to trigger the correct byte-array-to-string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

[Turns](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=ISO14443A) [out](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1Qqs-Q0aCI4), the UID is not always the same per technology. Here is the solution to that. Check which technology is in use and call the correct function to get the id as a `String`:

```
protected String getId(Tag tag) {
String id = null;

if (NfcA.get(tag) != null) {
        id = byteToString(tag.getId());
    } else if (NfcV.get(tag) != null) {
        id = byteToStringReversed(tag.getId());
    }
    return id;
}
```